# How to transform some VBScript code to C#

Tags: c#, vbscript

In my C# code, I currently reference a VBS file that runs a batch file. I'm doing this because it hides the CMD window (prevents it from being seen during execution). I have run into rights issues where the PC won't execute VBS files.

Is there anyway for me to replicate the VBS code in C#?

Here is the code:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c LayoutsBackup.bat"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

Comment: [Process.Start](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiM_8jy8t7VAhVkzVQKHfK4C58QFggvMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.diagnostics.process.start(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGlAKjUTat56iCorFFRRQ-DH8TPdQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below inside a new console project. Step through it using F10 and let me know if it helps.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
            var shellType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Wscript.Shell");
            dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellType);
            //Dim strArgs
            //strArgs = "cmd /c LayoutsBackup.bat"
            //oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
            var startArgs = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                Arguments = @"/c ""C:\YourPathTo\LayoutsBackup.bat""",                    FileName = "cmd",
                UseShellExecute = false
            };
            var shellProcess = Process.Start(startArgs);
            shellProcess.WaitForExit(); /* optional */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably need full pathnames of the cmd and bat files.

Comment: @jdweng Could be! On my laptop it doesn't. Win 7 Ent. You could try "win.exe" too. For me that also works.

Comment: @jdweng Do you mean the .bat file will have to be in the bin\Debug directory of the console app? I agree. I edited the answer. Thanks

Comment: I tried but it does not work. I just opens the cmd window to the location where the exe is launched from.